# Логические выражения в шаблонах Django

Tags: python, django

Шаблон

```
{% if first and second %}
    <!-- -->
{% endif %}
```

работает правильно, `<!-- -->` переходит в страницу HTML. А шаблон

```
{% if first == third and second == forth %}
    <!-- -->
{% endif %}
```

работает неправильно: `<!-- -->` не переходит в страницу HTML. В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: А у вас последний Django? До версии 1.2 оператор == не поддерживался.

Comment: Да, это Django 1.2. Спасибо за замечание, я не знал, что до версии 1.2 эти операторы не поддерживались.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрел [руководство](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs) Django:

> It is only possible to compare an argument to template variables or strings. You cannot check for equality with Python objects such as True or False. If you need to test if something is true or false, use the if tag instead.

В моем случае сравнивались объекты Питона, поэтому результат сравнения был не тот, который ожидался. Проверил - выражение вида

```
{% if "first" == "first" and "second" == "second" %}
    <!-- -->
{% endif %}
```

работает правильно: `<!-- -->` переходит в страницу HTML.